# Set videos with ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, video-streaming

Is it possible to set/run videos with asp.net? I mean - I have a database, where I store the videos and then I program a webpage in ASP.net where I want the user to run certain videos (.mp4, flash, etc.)... like user guide videos for smth.

If it's possible - any suggestions on what should I use, what libraries and tuts should I head to and so on.

This is the first time for me doing a web project and I am really lost.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can play the video using **ASP.net**. Check this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/CsharpWebVideo04212007133218PM/CsharpWebVideo.aspx

for more details http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/files,-images,-and-media/10-working-with-video

You can also download sample project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this HTML Code:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
<source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: How can this be done programmatically in a Visual Basic ASP.NET web application?